# Magento 2: How to call helper of other module if that module exists?

Tags: magento2

I want to call Helper of add-on module if that module is installed. I accomplish this by using `ObjectManager`, but as per Magento standards, `ObjectManager` should not be used.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config;

use Magento\Mtf\Client\BrowserInterface;

class CustomClass extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    const TEMPLATE = 'system/config/custom.phtml';
    private $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->objectManager    = $objectmanager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function checkClassData()
    {
        // This checks weather this "Module1" installed or not
        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Vendor1_Module1')) {
            // As "Module1" is installed so i want to use Helper of this module.
            $dataHelper = $this->objectManager->get("Vendor1\Module1\Helper\Data");
            $this->firstData      = $dataHelper->getFirstFunctionData();
        }
    }
}
```

What should i do to fulfill my requirements without `ObjectManager`.

Please help.

Comment: I don't think you don't have any other option.

Comment: use Dependency injection

Comment: I might be, but i am not sure about  Di injection.

Comment: @AmitBera The direct use of ObjectManager error while submitting extension on Magento marketplace.

Comment: @magefms can you please share your solution?

Comment: sorry,  don't have  enough idea

Comment: yeah sure I will

Comment: @magefms Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency injection at di.xml as 3rd party class, is your class argument.
A good example will Magento msi project

**Add 3rd party class as an argument to your class by add below code at di.xml**

```
 <type name="YourClass">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="{arguementname}" xsi:type="object">3rdpartyClass</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

at you can access that argument using `$this->get{{arguementname}}`.
**Example:**

```
  <type name="Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\UpdateSourceItemBasedOnLegacyStockItem">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sourceItemsSave" xsi:type="object">Magento\Inventory\Model\SourceItem\Command\SourceItemsSaveWithoutLegacySynchronization</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

line: https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/InventoryCatalog/etc/di.xml#L85-L89

Answer (score 0):

Helper call directly into the phtml by as below

```
$helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');
```

And also by construct as below

```
public function __construct(
   \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
   \Vendor\Magento\Helper\Data $customHelper,
   array $data = []
) {
   $this->customHelper= $customHelper;
   parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

It can easily accessible in this class by just calling as below

```
  $heper =  $this->customHelper;
```

Try this it's working for me.

Comment: If the module is disabled can you access the class files of that module? If yes then what is the meaning of module disabling & if no then how your dependency injection will work?

Comment: Yes, You can access that class if module is disabled.

If module is disabled that time its affect only on areas and routers of the modules.

Comment: @BhaumikRana what if the module does not exist? Will it throw errors during compile or on the phtml page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

In your code, inject a variable in constructor as follows.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config;

use Magento\Mtf\Client\BrowserInterface;

class CustomClass extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    const TEMPLATE = 'system/config/custom.phtml';
    private $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper $customHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
       $this->objectManager    = $objectmanager;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);

       $this->customHelper = $customHelper;
    }

    public function checkClassData()
    {
        // This checks weather this "Module1" installed or not
        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Vendor1_Module1')) {
            // As "Module1" is installed so i want to use Helper of this module.
            $this->firstData      = $this->customHelper->getFirstFunctionData();
        }
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config\CustomClass">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="customHelper" xsi:type="object">Vendor1\Module1\Helper\Data</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

This means that your helper and the default datatype of $customHelper both would be **\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper**

So in case even if another module does not exist, it wont throw any error, because the AbstractHelper will always be there.

This way you can avoid use of ObjectManager.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But after implementation of your code, I am getting the error: main.CRITICAL: Class Vendor1\Module1\Helper\Data does not exist

Comment: I see, In that case probably you have only one option to give expalination to magento why you have to use objectManager as i dont see any other option.